# Creating 3D halftone wavy effect using any tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, effects, halftone

I am looking to reproduce this effect. I've scoured the internet, but couldn't find any plugin/tutorial that replicates this exact effect.[image: This is the halftone wavy effect I'm looking to be reproduced. The depth and the change in density is what I particularly want in the end result. Preferably in vector format.]

Comment: Magic! But no, you can do this with any 3d software package or even After Effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that *particular* image may have been generated by a 3D application. Which one is your choice.

Illustrator can do this to a degree, but it won't easily create the depth of the bump texture. You have to kind of fake it.

Draw a couple random paths....

[image]

Select both paths and choose `Object > Blend > Make` from the menu.

Then choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options...` from the menu, tick the `Preview` box and set the drop down to **Specified Steps**, then input a number of steps to create a clear transition between the lines without too much space or so tight you can't see any separation:

[image]

In the **Stroke Panel** tick the **Dashed Line** option and set the fist `dash` field to 0pt, then set the first `Gap` field to twice the size of your stroke weight. Then tick the rounding options (highlighted in magenta below):

[image]
<sup>(Right-Click/Control-Click and choose `Open image in new tab/window` to see it larger.)</sup>

From there it's all a matter of colors..... and repeating the same steps for more shapes.

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can edit the paths to refine where the dots fall, you can alter the blend steps to increase frequency, and you can alter stroke weights to change the size of the dots.

I realize this *is not nearly as smooth and doesn't possess the depth of field in your sample*. But this is as close as Illustrator can get. And much of the appearance depends upon how long you set it up. This was a quick example and hasn't really been refined to any degree. Adding masks and hiding sections would result in a close to your sample match.

Comment: This got me thinking if you fill the shape then it would do rudimenray blackface culling